# To prove magnitude of regression coefficient is less in 1st model than in 2nd model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, residuals

[image]

My intuition for solving the question is that when we regress the residual on X3 , we're basically regressing X1 after eliminating the Linear effect of X2 from it on X3. So the coefficient of X3 here will tell us the change in magnitude of X1 after eliminating Linear effect of X2.

Now when we regress simultaneously, the coefficient of X3 will be interpreted as the change in magnitude of X1 while keeping X2 constant. Now it's plausible that X3 will explain more in X1 since the Linear effect has not been eliminated.

So we can say that coefficient of X3 will have  more magnitude in 2nd model than in 1st Model.

Equality will hold when Correlation between X2 and X3 is 0.

But I don't know how to prove it. Some help in proving the inequality will be really appreciated and also I would like to know if my intuition is correct.